# How do I remove a segment without affecting another

Tags: iis, rewrite

Looking for help creating an IIS rewrite rule.

We have a distributable product that is installed in an unknown base url

We want to block `/app` and do so using:

```
<remove segment="app"/>
```

However there is now a new path (`/frontend/app/js/files.js`), and our command was also blocking files in this folder.

How do I update the rule to only block `/app` but not block `/frontend/app/js`

Thanks!